# Multiple consecutive join with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to join multiple DF together. Because how join work, I got the same column name duplicated all over.

> When called on datasets of type (K, V) and (K, W), returns a dataset
>   of (K, (V, W)) pairs with all pairs of elements for each key.

```
# Join Min and Max to S1
joinned_s1 = (minTime.join(maxTime, minTime["UserId"] == maxTime["UserId"]))

# Join S1 and sum to s2
joinned_s2 = (joinned_s1.join(sumTime, joinned_s1["UserId"] == sumTime["UserId"]))
```

I got this error: ""Reference 'UserId' is ambiguous, could be: UserId#1578, UserId#3014.;"

What is the proper way of removing W from my dataset once successfully joined?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use equi-join:

```
 minTime.join(maxTime, ["UserId"]).join(sumTime, ["UserId"])
```

aliases:

```
minTime.alias("minTime").join(
    maxTime.alias("maxTime"), 
    col("minTime.UserId") == col("maxTime.UserId")
)
```

or reference parent table:

```
(minTime
  .join(maxTime, minTime["UserId"] == maxTime["UserId"])
  .join(sumTime, minTime["UserId"] == sumTime["UserId"]))
```

On as side note you're quoting `RDD` docs, not `DataFrame` ones. These are different data structures and don't operate in the same way.

Also it looks like you're doing something strange here. Assuming you have a single parent table `min`, `max` and `sum` can be computed as simple aggregations without `join`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. 
@zero323 - I've tried something like 
dfg = df.groupBy(df.UserId).agg({"Timer": "sum","Timer": "min","Timer": "max","Timer": "avg", "Actions": "count"}) but only the AVG shows-up... thus the use of join.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Created a new thread to cover above question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488817/pyspark-multiple-aggregation-funtions-on-a-single-column-of-a-dataframe

Answer (score 5):

If you join two data frames on columns then the columns will be duplicated. So try to use an array or string for joining two or more data frames.

For example, if joining on columns:

```
df = left.join(right, left.name == right.name)
```

Output will consist of two columns with "name".

Now if you use:

```
df = left.join(right, "name") OR df=left.join(right,["name"])
```

Then output will not have duplicate columns.