# How to union columns from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark

I have three dataframes that I am trying to unionize based on values of a specific column. I am not sure if `.join()` is the best method (as I have to scale to over 20 dataframes).

I've read that aggregating may also be possible in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38469777/12055013), but I'm not sure if it's appropriate for my use case.

```
a = |loc|sale|address|
    |1  |32  |foo    |
    |2  |12  |bar    |

b = |loc|app |ident  |
    |1  |32  |000    |


c = |loc|spa |cater  |
    |1  |11  |332    |
    |2  |99  |252    |
```

Note that column `loc` is the only field that's in all three dataframes. And dataframe `b` has no row with `loc=2`.

I've tried equi-join but I'm running into a two issues

`test = a.join(b, ['loc'], how='outer').join(c, ['loc'], how='outer')`

```
My expected result is: 

test = |loc|sale|address|app |ident | spa | cater |
       |1  |32  |foo    |32  |000   |11   | 332   |
       |2  |12  |bar    |None|None  |99   | 252   |


My actual result is:
test = |loc|sale|address|app |ident | spa | cater |
       |1  |None|None   |32  |000   |11   | 332   |
       |2  |None|None   |None|None  |99   | 252   |
```

The unwanted result is that the columns `sale` and `address` from my first left dataframe, `a`, are filled with `None` when they should actually have carry the values from `a`. I need to make sure each row has the same number of columns, including row `loc=2` even though it is entirely missing in dataframe `b`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Seems like changing those `"outer"`s to `"left"` would work, or am I missing something?

Comment: Also you should [edit] your question to specify if you're working on spark DataFrames vs pandas Dataframes.

Comment: I am not able to replicate the issue you are mentioning and the results of the code below look like what you mentioned to be the expected result:
```
a = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 32, "foo"), (2, 12, "bar")], ["loc", "sale", "address"])
b = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 23, "000")], ["loc", "app", "ident"])
c = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 11, 332), (2, 99, 252)], ["loc", "spa", "cater"])
joinedDFs = a.join(b, ['loc'], how='outer').join(c, ['loc'], how='outer')
```